# Como implementar um mapa que mostra as unidades de uma determinada loja em um site

Tags: javascript, html5

Preciso fazer uma aplicação que mostre as unidades disponíveis de uma loja no mapa.

Por exemplo: Há um campo onde o usuário irá inserir seu Bairro, Município e Cidade, baseado nessas informações tenho que trazer os resultados próximos em formato de lista, até aí tudo bem, na lista tem um botão "ver mapa" e quando o usuário clicar quero abrir o mapa dentro de meu site (na mesma página) mas ai não sei muito bem como fazer ou como começar essa parte.

Comment: Você quer utilizar o Google map?

Comment: Você pode utilizar a API Simple Markers do Google Maps. Link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

Answer (score 7):

uma boa opção é utilizar a [API do google maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/).

aqui você pode ver alguns [tutoriais](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) e um exemplo funcionando:

http://www.princiweb.com.br/demos/google-maps-api-v3-busca-endereco-autocomplete/
fontes: https://github.com/rodolfoprr/GoogleMapsAPIv3ProcuraEnderecoAutocomplete

basicamente o que você precisa é importar a api javascript e css

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

uma div

```
<div id="mapa"></div>
```

e inicializar seu mapa

```
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-18.8800397, -47.05878999999999);
    var options = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), options);

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
    });

    marker.setPosition(latlng);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

utilizando a api você pode exibir o mapa de cidades, estados, países, etc... e marcar um ou vários endereços.